# No empirical results in papers

Tags: discussion

I am new to the Computer Science field and I've started reading papers. One thing I noticed is that in most of the papers I read, the authors never bother to code their new algorithm on a pc and produce empirical results. Are you not supposed to produce empirical results when you are using the scientific method? That's what I learned.
An example of such paper. It's a paper about the fastest MST algorithm.
http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/pubs/mst.pdf

Comment: This shouldn't be on the meta site. I would migrate it to the regular cstheory.stackexchange.com site, but I feel that this question is too argumentative. If you can rephrase the question in a more neutral fashion, then maybe it will be suitable for the main site.

Comment: It's not hostile. I am French, sorry for my english...

Comment: I think this question could receive a decent answer if posted on the main site. But it's probably not a research-level question.